# Display Tooltip on Switchery

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip, switchery

currently I try to implement the [Switchery](https://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/) with a bootstrap tooltip when the switch is true or false.

I try to manage the display of information on the tooltip, but I can't seem to realize that...

My code look like this:
http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FB7Y3M04MBL1

How a can fixe this ?

**EDITE:** I've found the solution:  http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FB7ZGYFV9AYY
Bootstrap change *title* by *data-original-title*

Answer (score 1):

Add span tag before input field of Switchery and place tooltip attributes to that span tag

```
<span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!"><input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" /></span>
```